# Javascript/node link main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am just learning and I am trying to build a web app using node, I know I could use express but I am trying to build it all using Node to get a better understanding.

The problem is I cant get the main.js page to load on the app.
I have a router module that builds the page eg

```
function home(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(fs.readFileSync('./views/header.html'));
    res.write('<style>' + fs.readFileSync('./css/styles.css') + '</style>');
    res.write(fs.readFileSync('./views/startpage.html'));
    res.end(fs.readFileSync('./views/footer.html'));
};
```

and the script tag is in the footer partial just before the closing body tag, would i need to load it a different way ?

Here is the full app if this is not enough information, thanks
https://github.com/naassi/taxi-log

Comment: the goodway could be using a framework, like `express` and a template engine like `jade` or `ejs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a static file server for all your css and javascript files. Instead of sending the CSS file content in home, include 
`<style>./css/styles.css</style>`, and answer the request for *.css files with the appropriate file:

```
function staticServer(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
      return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
})
```

In footer, you want to load a .js file - your Node server is responsible for serving that, just like it handles a request for e.g., home.

If you're learning Node, try to stay away fron Sync functions, they block the event loop, and defeat Node's good parts :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I have a lot more to learn about node js, should the staticserver function repalce my home route and I don't understand how I can use the server to serve the data and the js file ?

Comment: I would start with a smaller example: Load one html file, if you want in your home function. Then include css from inside your html file. Inside your home function, you can parse the request url. If it ends in .css, load and serve the css file, otherwise do what you currently do in home. Then extends that to not only check for .css, but .js and so on.

Comment: Instead of doing fs.read() in your home function, I'd write out the html you want to serve. That might make it easier to understand what's going on. Work in small steps, then include more content!